# Problems deleting an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding new functionalities to my web design and I'm having problems with an absurd thing with jQuery.

I've an  element that I want it make an append when it's clicked.

My code is:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#list").append("<div id=\"item\"></div>");
});
```

And it runs quite good. The problem is that this new element (div) is only showed while the function is running (every time I clicked, it appears and disappears).

I've seen a lot of examples how to do this and everywhere people says that this is the correct way, but in my case, it isn't.

How I can solve this stupid problem?

Comment: And would `#add` by any chance be an anchor ?

Comment: You can't use duplicate IDs in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is the item is added, then the page reloads afresh and you don't see the item any more.  You probably need to prevent the default action of whatever you are clicking on:

```
$("#add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#list").append("<div id=\"item\"></div>");
});
```

If this is ever going to be clicked more than once, then you shouldn't have duplicate ID values either so perhaps use a class name:

```
$("#add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#list").append('<div class="item"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Satpal suggested , you cannot use duplicate ID names in HTML . Instead you could use a class name for your appended item .

```
$("#list").append("<div class=\"item\"></div>");
```

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/6m2Gx/

Comment: Also provide an example, if `#add` happens to be an anchor